# Print cross pattern in Java

Tags: java, printing

I've got this homework exercise that I'm stuck on.

Basically we have to print a cross pattern with 'X' character, but the middle bit has to be empty.

So, the program has to read an integer from the command line and after executing it it should output a cross pattern.

Something like this:
 
        `x 
        x
        x
  x x x   x x x
        x
        x
        x`

Hopefully you can see it formatted properly above, basically I don't how to add that empty bit in the middle.

This is what I have so far:

`public class Cross {`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int num = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) 
{
  num = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
    drawCross(num);
}
}


public static void drawCross(int num){

 for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) 
 {
        for(int j = 0; j < num; j++) 
        {

            if((i == num / 2) || (j == num / 2)) 
                System.out.print("X ");

            else 
               System.out.print(" ");
               System.out.print(" ");

    }
    System.out.println();
        }

}
}
```

Now, this above works, but it prints a normal cross, without the gap in the middle. (Also, I'm guessing that there's a smarter way of doing this instead of using sysout)

The only other requirements that they gave us are that the 'x' should be printed *4n* times and that the program must handle invalid inputs.

I would appreciate if you guys can give me a hand!
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked for me:

```
public static void drawCross(int num){
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < num; j++){
            if((i == num / 2) || (j == num / 2)){
                if((i == (num-1) / 2) == (j == (num-1) / 2)){
                    System.out.print(" ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("X");
                }
            } else { 
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This does work, but only with odd numbers, for some reason. Does the same happen with you?

Comment: You can't print a cross with even numbers. If you do, one side will be longer than the other.

Comment: Oh god, of course. Thanks! Also, do you know how do I correctly display the number of 'x' that has been printed? Because, if I just do this 'System.out.println("X was printed " + 2*num + " times");'  the result will of course not be correct.

Comment: @user3520281 2 * num - 2. Since this length of the height and width is num you have 2n, -2 comes from the blank spot which is where they intercept -1 for height and -1 again for width.

Answer (score 4):

I would use the XOR operator, `^`, between the conditions.  The bitwise operators `|`, `&`, and `^` work on `boolean`s too.

```
if((i == num / 2) ^ (j == num / 2))
```

That way, if *exactly* one of the conditions is `true`, then your `"X "` will be printed.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This actually does create the gap, but it's a bit offset. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: You'll still need to print the gap if both conditions are true.

Answer (score 0):

This Works for me:

```
public class DrawPattern {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int i, j;
            int num = 7;
            for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < num; j++) {
                    if (isConditionMatch(num, i, j)) {
                        System.out.print("X");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

        }

        private static boolean isConditionMatch(int num, int i, int j) {
            return (i != j && (i == (num - 1) / 2 || j == (num - 1) / 2));
        }

    }
```

Output:

```
   X   
   X   
   X   
XXX XXX
   X   
   X   
   X
```